# torrent works but browser doesn't work

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, internet, browser, utorrent

After I setup  [µTorrent](http://www.utorrent.com/#comp-tbl) to download my torrents , i face a strange behavior when working with torrents for a long time.

---

The torrent works very well but when i try my browser to go to any web site , i can't access even though the ping for these web sites success !!

How to overcome this problem ? I try to disable and enable the network but in vain .

Comment: Do you actually mean you can't browse sites when uTorrent is running? If so, reduce the number of connections in Preferences > Bandwidth. Most users tend to go overboard with these numbers thinking big numbers are necessary for optimal bandwidth, when it's not.

Comment: @geewee:yeah after a couble of hours using utorrent wehn i try to browse any website i can't ..

Comment: @geewee : Could u clarify how to reduce the number of connections .(in steps)

Comment: My experience with uTorrent - is that after torrenting for a while, and even after closing uTorrent - the network is still unstable as lots of peers seems to still trying to connect and saturates the network. My usual solution is to restart your ADSL/Cable Modem and that seems to work for me. So not just your own PC network, but the cable/adsl modem itself.

Answer (score 1):

In uTorrent, press CTRL+P to open the *Preferences* dialog. Click on *Bandwidth* on the left sidebar. You should see three input boxes under *Number of Connections*. Try to halve the value in each. You may have to experiment with the values to strike the right balance.

Also, it is advisable to limit the number of running torrents to keep uTorrent from saturating your local network and Internet link. In the *Preferences* dialog, click on *Queueing* on the left sidebar. Halve the values inside *Queue Settings* (there are two).

One last thing to keep in mind is that uTorrent (or any other BitTorrent client) may irritate other users in your network because of clogged bandwidth and increased latency, so be prepared to receive complaints and compromise accordingly. I personally only run any kind of BitTorrent client late at night, before I go to bed when there is nobody using the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

This is very possibly a dns issue?

Torrent will be connected already so wont' be bothered by dns not working, but every request to connect to a website or ping a name eg `ping google.com`requires a dns lookup.

Try changing your DNS servers your machine uses in the properties of your network card.  Details in link below.

https://www.opennicproject.org/configure-your-dns/how-to-change-dns-servers-in-windows-7/

Change them to different dns servers from the ones your using such as

```
Google DNS Servers
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
```

or

```
OpenDNS IP Addresses
208.67.222.222
208.67.220.220
```